# How to avoid calling ngBlur's action if the input's value is not changed?

Tags: angularjs, input

I have the following input in my page:

```
<input ng-blur="dataChanged(node)"  type="text" ng-currency min="0" fraction='currentShop.currency.fraction' currency-symbol='{{currentShop.currency.symbol}}' ng-model="node.price" placeholder="{{'Price' | translate}}">
```

It calls dataChanged every time input lost its focus even the data wasn't changed.

How can I avoid this?